# SAS custom keys (F12) clearing but then running script without command

Tags: sas

I've set up in SAS 9.4 my F12 to clear my log, results, and HTML output. I use this all the time and have for years and now suddenly when I use F12 it does the requested clear but also will run the most recent program. It's a huge pain in the ass. Any insights on what's up or how I can change the DM Keys code below to fix it? thanks!

`clear log; clear results; clear output; end;`

Answer (score 1):

Okay- appears it was the addition of `end;` which was running the program. Solved.